# Select Query with Multiple IN Collection in Where Clause in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having Question and Answer (Multiple Choice) Table. The Answer Table contains both Question ID and Answer ID (its not a Unique ID).

Refer the Answer Table:

```
QID       AID        Answer
_______________________________
 1         1          Good
 1         2          Very Good
 1         3          Excellent
 2         1          Delhi
 2         2          Mumbai
 2         3          Chennai
 2         4          Kolkata
```

The User Answered for Question 1 (QID) is 2 (AID) and Question 2 (QID) is 3 (AID).

I need to

`SELECT the Answer "Very Good" (1 -> 2) and "Chennai" (2 -> 3).`

```
(QID -> AID) => {(1 -> 2), (2 -> 3), .... n} sets
```

I don't have the Primary Key. Within this Table Structure how to achieve my Selection ? Kindly assist me...

Comment: Your question is not clear, what you trying to get from that table? What is your condition to get record?

Comment: The User Selected  (QID -> AID) => {(1 -> 2), (2 -> 3)} sets. I need to select the records. as mentioned in the sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query

```
// example array
$user_selected_array=array(
    0=>array(1,2),
    1=>array(2,3)
);
$WHERE='';
foreach($user_selected_array as $key=>$val) {
    $WHERE .= ($WHERE!='')?" OR ":"";
    $WHERE .= "(QID=$val[0] AND AID=$val[1])";
}

SELECT Answer FROM AnswerTable WHERE $WHERE
```

Comment: you can replace `Answer` with `*` to get all fields

Comment: Its a N number of sets, how to construct the WHERE clause?

Comment: If you having the user selection as an array, then you can create the WHERE clause with foreach